# Convert multiple rows into single in datatable

Tags: linq, datatable

I have a DataTable in C# with two columns

```
State    Region
A        1
A        2
B        3
B        4
```

What I want to achieve is

```
State    Region
A        1,2
B        3,4
```

Is this possible in C# with a single LINQ query?

I am not good in LINQ and also don't want to loop through table to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(row => row.Field<string>("State"))
            .Select(g =>
                {
                    var row = dataTable.NewRow();
                    row.ItemArray = new object[]
                    {
                        g.Key, 
                        string.Join(",", 
                                  g.Select(r => r.Field<string>("Region")))
                    };

                    return row;
                }).CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Cuong Le: Thanks for the single line solution! The result is coming in expected format. However, the second column displays comma separated "System.Data.DataRow, System.Data.DataRow" instead of actual regions

Answer (score 0):

Use GroupBy to achieve this as follow....

```
var groupedData = from b in dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                  group b by b.Field<string>("State") into g
                  select new
                  {
                      State = g.Key,
                      Regions = g,                      
                  };
```

Then you can iterate through each group to get Data...

```
foreach (var g in groupedData) 
        {                
            foreach (var w in g.Regions) 
            { 
                Console.WriteLine(w); 
            } 
        }
```