# Multiple rows to column

Tags: linq-to-sql, linq-to-objects

I have table like this

```
ID  message
1   jame
1   cluster
1   alpha
2   apple
2   orange
```

How to use LINQ to give answer like below

```
ID Message
1  Jame,cluster,alpha
2  apple,orange
```

I saw the below URL but its not working for me
[Convert multiple rows into single in datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066108/convert-multiple-rows-into-single-in-datatable)
I am getting error while performing `string.join` in the LINQ given in the above link.

My code same as above link

```
      var result = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
        .GroupBy(row => row.Field<int>("ID"))
        .Select(g =>
            {
                var row = dataTable.NewRow();
                row.ItemArray = new object[]
                {
                    g.Key, 
                    string.Join(",", 
                              g.Select(r => r.Field<string>("message")))
                };

                return row;
            }).CopyToDataTable();
```

Error Message : Argument 2: Connot convert from System.Collection.generic.IEnumerable to string[]

Comment: Errors contain all kinds of useful information, which we now lack.

Comment: Error Message : Connot convert from System.Collection.generic.IEnumerable to string[]

Comment: So what does your code look like?

Comment: var result = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(row => row.Field<int>("ID"))
            .Select(g =>
                {
                    var row = dataTable.NewRow();
                    row.ItemArray = new object[]
                    {
                        g.Key, 
                        string.Join(",", 
                                  g.Select(r => r.Field<string>("message")))
                    };

                    return row;
                }).CopyToDataTable();

Answer (score 1):

With `linq-to-objects` you can do this

```
var query = from x in list
            group x by x.ID into g
            select new
            {
              ID = g.Key,
              Message = string.Join(",", g.Select(x => x. Message)),
            };
```

With `linq-to-sql` you can do the grouping with `linq-to-sql`, but the string aggregation has to be done with `linq-to-objects`

```
var query = (from x in db.list
            group x by x.ID into g
            select g).AsEnumerable().Select(g =>
              ID = g.Key,
              Message = string.Join(",", g.Select(x => x. Message)),
            );
```

Comment: "Officially" `string.Join` is better because it doesn't create new strings for each step as `Aggregate` does.

Comment: can you tell me how to take out from table instead of list ?